# How to Airplay video received in CVPixelBuffer along with audio received from a separate source?

Tags: ios, airplay, cvpixelbuffer

I have iOS application that receives video in CVPixelBuffers, processes video frames with Metal framework and displays the result on the CAMetalLayer. I need to make the app able to show processed video via Airplay on connected receiver(AppleTV, Mac book, etc.).

The only my accomplishment is that my app writes video to file via AVAssetWriter and after writing it finished, video is played by AVPlayer and automatically re-directed to connected Airplay receiver. But this flow absolutely doesn't match the task. The task is to stream video, kind of live stream to Airplay receiver but not to play video recorded to file. I have already read bunch of documentation about Airplay, but didn't find even a direction of further development. Well appreciate any ideas.